# What is the error in this MySQL Update statement?

Tags: mysql, datetime

```
UPDATE `module_adobeConnect_sessions` SET `date_begin` = DATE_SUB(`date_begin`, INTERVAL 7 HOURS);
```

The error that I get is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'HOURS)' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interval type needs to be in singular - that is: `INTERVAL 7 HOUR`, not `HOURS`. I'll grant you it's a very easy mistake to make.